# Xcode 4 & Xcode 3.2.6

Tags: xcode

Can you have Xcode 4 and Xcode 3.2.6 on the same Lion Mac at the same time? Or can you only have one instance of Xcode installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. During the Xcode install process, you can select the folder where it is installed. Install one in (e.g.) /Developer and the other in /Developer4. I did that and it works fine.

Comment: If you use [Cocotron](http://cocotron.org), though, be aware that it is hard-coded to install in /Developer. But it's highly unlikely that you're using Cocotron.

Comment: [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/ExistingProject/ExistingProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009984-CH2-SW23) specifically states that you can have both installed at the same time.